# Unable to select right click in dotty (Graphviz)

Tags: linux, graphviz

I am currently running Backtrack 5R3 32-bit version and when I go to right click in dotty or lneato, I get the menu, but I am unable to select anything. When I mouse over them, it doesn't highlight, and when I let go of the mouse, the menu disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz/+bug/160315

It looks like there's a bug on Linux involving Numlock. Try turning off Numlock.